# How to build a string from items that are clicked?

Tags: java, android, string, stringbuilder

I'm trying to make a one String from views that are clicked and store them in database. I have created a list of different views and I want to save only the clicked ones.

```
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
final String prefix = " ";


    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        boolean isClicked = false;


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (isClicked) {
                isClicked = false;

            } else {
                String ingredient = holder.ingredientTextView.getText().toString();
                sb.append(ingredient);
                sb.append(prefix);
                isClicked = true;
            }
        }
    });
    allIngredients = sb.toString();
```

Comment: You need to give us some code...and then what you have tried so far.

Comment: So you want to create a string listing all the items clicked in order?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Comment: @GursheeshSingh exactly

Comment: You can check my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Declare a StringBuilder

   `private StringBuilder viewClickingOrder = new StringBuilder();`
2. Attach a onClickListener to each view

   `view.setOnClickListener(this);`
3. Create a common listener

   `@Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
       viewClickingOrder.append(view.getClass().getName());

   }`

   If you want or have different click listener behavior just add this line

   `viewClickingOrder.append(view.getClass().getName());`

   to each listener